# $\sum_{i=1}^n g(i) = \mathcal{O}(\sum_{i=1}^n h(i))$ imply that $g(n) = \mathcal{O}(h(n))$

Tags: algorithms, time-series, algorithmic-game-theory

Does   $\sum_{i=1}^n g(i) = \mathcal{O}(\sum_{i=1}^n (h(i)))$ imply that $g(n)=
\mathcal{O}(h(n))$ when $g,h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R+}$?

I think this statement is wrong.

Is the following a valid counterexample ?

$g(n)=1 , \;\; h(n)=(\frac{1}{n})$

or this statment is actually true and i need to prove it ?

Comment: Please use MathJax to formulate your symbols and equations; here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: MathJax works in the title too.

Comment: Of course not, try $$g(2n)=h(2n+1)=1\qquad g(2n+1)=h(2n)=n$$

Comment: yeah i am thinking about a series that is's sum is n right now

Comment: i didn't figure it out .. why you used 2n and how can i use this in the series .. sisnce i need functions of n

Comment: could you give me just a little hint ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the summatory function of  $g$ is $\sim n$ but the summatory function of $h$ is $\sim \log n$ so the assumption is not satisfied.